# getting no output (expecting boolean output)

Tags: c, equality, c-strings, return-type, function-definition

So I tried not using the string.h file. I created string length function which works. I then created a function to check if two functions are same or not but I am getting no output.
I have tested the string length function and that works. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the second function. Please point out the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char stringLength(char userString[])
{
    int i=0,count=0;
    while (userString[i] != '\0')
    {
        count = (count + 1);
        i = (i + 1);
    }
    return count;

}


bool stringCheck (char a[], char b[])
{
    bool isEquals = false;
    if (stringLength(a) == stringLength(b))
    {
        int i=0, count=0;
        while (i<stringLength(a))
        {
            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                count+=1;
            }

            i+=1;
        }

        if (count == stringLength(a))
            isEquals = true;
        else
            isEquals = false;
    }
    else
        isEquals = false;

    return isEquals;
}

int main()
{
    stringCheck("abcd", "abcd");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not stored the return value of `stringCheck` when called from `main`. So how are you determining the function failed? If that's not the problem then step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: On a side note: It is inefficient to call `stringLength` multiple times on the same string. Better to store the length in a variable and use that wherever it is needed.

Comment: Another side note: Using the return type `char` for `stringLength` means it will only work for strings up to 127 characters long on some platforms, and for strings up to 255 characters long on some other platforms. Since you are using `int` variables to hold the length, it would be better to use return type `int`. (Actually, it would be better to use `size_t` instead of `int` since that matches the `strlen` function.)

Comment: The absence of a function producing any form of output would explain the lack of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function works.

Its just that you are not catching the return value of `stringCheck()` function. You can do that as shown below.

```
bool strMatch = stringCheck("abcd", "abcd");
if(true == strMatch)
{
    // Do something when the strings are same
}
else
{
    // Do something else otherwise
}
```

Also, as an improvement - In `stringCheck()` function, you have a loop

```
while (i < stringLength(a))
```

There is nothing wrong with it, but you can improve the efficiency of your code by saving the length of the string into a variable and use that variable for polling in the `while` loop.
In `stringCheck` function:

```
int i=0, count=0;
char strLength = stringLength(a);
while (i < strLength)
```

This will work because the length of strings aren't changing within the loop.

I find issues with `stringLength()` function. First is, the data type used for variable returning the length `count` is `int` whereas the return type set for function is `char`. Also, consider changing the return type of the function `stringLength()` to `size_t` along with the data type for variable `count` in the same function.

```
char stringLength(char userString[])
```

to

```
size_t stringLength(char userString[])
```

With a return type as `char`, your function will misbehave if the length of the string is more than 127 bytes.

The next improvement in the `stringLength()` function is, `i` and `count` seems to be updated at the same time. I can't think why you need two variables there when you can simply return `i` in place of `count`.

Your compiler would have warned you about all these points if you had compiled your code with certain gcc flags such as `-Wall` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

AS @WedaPashi says, your code works. You just need to use the result.

But your code is overly complicated. There's absolutely no reason whatsoever to use two variables in the first function. Also, the first function should not return a char (unless you want the function to not work on strings longer than 127 or 255 characters) Use `int` or preferably `size_t` instead. Do like this:

```
size_t stringLength(char userString[])
{
    int count=0;
    while (userString[i] != '\0') 
        count++;

    return count;
}
```

And for your second function, it's just a waste of time comparing their lengths. Here is a much simpler implementation:

```
bool stringCheck (char a[], char b[])
{
    size_t index = 0;
    while(a[index] != '\0') {
        if(a[index] != b[index]) return false;
        index++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you want you could also add some checking if the arguments are null pointers.

Comment: Yes I realized that I made it way too complex. I just started learning the C language. Thanks a lot for pointing out better solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the return value from the function `stringCheck` in `main`

```
int main()
{
    stringCheck("abcd", "abcd");
    return 0;
}
```

At least you could write for example

```
int main( void )
{
    printf( "Strings are %sequal\n", stringCheck("abcd", "abcd") ? "" : "not " );
    return 0;
}
```

Apart from this your code is very inefficient and in general even can invoke undefined behavior.

For example the function `stringLength` will return incorrect length of strings that have more than `127` or `255` characters depending on whether the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

The function should be declared like

```
size_t stringLength( const char userString[] )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( userString[count] != '\0' ) ++count;

    return count;
}
```

Or for example within the function `stringCheck` the function `stringLength` is called for each value of the variable `i` in the loop

```
    int i=0, count=0;
    while (i<stringLength(a))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function parameters should be declared with the qualifier `const` because  passed strings are not changed within the function.

In fact the function `stringLength` is redundant. The function `stringCheck` can be written without using the function `stringLength` much simpler.

Here you are.

```
bool stringCheck( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    return *s1 == *s2;
}
```